type flutter doctor get zsh: command not found: flutter in macOs
I use Sidekick to install Flutter SDK, I use the GUI to see the Cache location is
/Users/motogod19/fvm/versions/3.12.0
and then I open terminal

open bash_profile

open -e ~/.bash_profile

enter the path into bash_profile and save it

export PATH=/Users/motogod19/fvm/versions/3.12.0
3.
source ~/.bash_profile
4.
flutter doctor
Finally I get zsh: command not found: flutter
What step is wrong ?
Is my path is not corrrect ?

You are getting error because your path flutter sdk path is wrong. You have to add bin folder also. Like this.
export PATH=/Users/motogod19/fvm/versions/3.12.0/bin

After that run this commands.
source ~/.bash_profile

flutter doctor

